# Jplayer music does not stop and will keep playing in the background and clash in IE9

Tags: jquery, drupal, jplayer

I have used a jplayer module to play MP3 files in a popup. But I am getting a problem: When I close the popup, the song is still played. I want the player stops when I close the popup. This problem only appears with Internet Explorer 9.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: You can find js from this link because I have used same js module in drupal.
http://www.jplayer.org/

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I was using Drupal.CTools.Modal.dismiss() method to close popup which was conflicting with jplayer js to stop. So, I rmoved that and on click set the css for popup display none and jplyer stopped playing on closing the popup. So, it was not the jplayer problem, it was due to conflict of the method used to close the popup.